# Raspberry Pi can't play sound file

Tags: python, audio, raspberry-pi

I want to play a sound in my python file of Raspberry Pi:

```
import playsound
playsound.playsound('morning.mp3',True)
```

But I got this error:

> Valueerror : Namespace Gst not available

I couldn't find how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the console and type

```
sudo apt-get install python-gst-1.0
```

Run your program again and it should solve your problem